# How can I format a Twig Calculation?

Tags: twig

How can I format a Twig Calculation?
Currently I am using the following Code:

```
£{{ (Results.Result._symbol_at_attributes.adults + 
Results.Result._symbol_at_attributes.children) * 
Results.Result._symbol_at_attributes.price / 100 * 95  }}
```

Current Example Output: £459.4

Needed Output: £459

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin filter [number_format](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html).

```
£{{ ((Results.Result._symbol_at_attributes.adults + Results.Result._symbol_at_attributes.children) * Results.Result._symbol_at_attributes.price / 100 * 95) | number_format  }}
```

---

*Do note: you have to add parantheses around the calculation, otherwise the filter would only be applied to the last part of the calculation due to the [precedence of operators](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#expressions)*